# Select record using FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, select

I am storing the check box value as comma separated value in db like

```
Features

1,3,4

1,2,3,4,5

3,4,5,6
```

Now while searching i need to select the record based on the user select the check-box, say example if user selects `1 and 6` needs to fetch matched record. I am getting selected check-box value as array like `(0=>1,1=>6)`. I dont know how to loop through this like `FIND_IN_SET(1,Features) OR FIND_IN_SET(6,Features)`

It has to come like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1,Features) OR FIND_IN_SET(6,Features)
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `features` column?

Comment: do you want to select that row which have only `1,6` OR which contains atleast 1 or 6 ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b7b7/1

Comment: @diEcho **features** datatype is varchar, and i need either 1 or 6 in the features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str='%';
foreach($array as $val)
{$str.=$val.'%';}

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Features like $str
```

Update:

```
$str='';
    foreach($array as $val)
    {$str.='or Feature like %'.$val.'%';}
$str[0]='';$str[1]='';

    SELECT * FROM table WHERE $str
```

Comment: Hi, i need to select either 1 or 6. The query you posted is fetching both 1 and 6

Comment: ican't quite get you,this query will fetch all the rows which have 1 as well as 6.Now what's wrong

Comment: if the record has 1,3,4 and 6,7 both needs to fetch if the person select 1 and 6, but in your case not fetching %1%6%

Comment: don't forget to click on the check mark at the left side of answer

Comment: `select * from luxury_properties LP,property_type PT,cities C where ( FIND_IN_SET('2',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) OR FIND_IN_SET('7',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) ) AND LP.property_type_id = PT.property_type_id AND LP.city=C.city_id AND LP.status=1 order by LP.property_price DESC` this code works in phpmyadmin but getting error in php. can you find out the error?

Comment: in php file you have to connect to database first and then execute this query

Comment: Its working if i remove FIND_IN_SET part, problem is withh FIND_IN_SET am i executing correct way?

Comment: just ask a question on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

I fixed using the below code to get query like this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1,Features) OR FIND_IN_SET(6,Features)`

```
if($selCount >1){
    foreach($luxPropFeatures as $val) {
      $str .="OR FIND_IN_SET('".$val."',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) ";
      $trimmed = ltrim($str, "OR"); 
      //$str[0]='';$str[2]='';
     }
}else{

    foreach($luxPropFeatures as $val) {
        $trimmed = "FIND_IN_SET('".$val."',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) ";
    }

}
```